# <h:outputText> how to display content with fixed length?

Tags: java, html, jsf-2

I have a string like this:

```
<p><strong>Make sure you’re paying the right price for your household and trade services with pricing calculators from Australia’s largest online services marketplace, ServiceSeeking.com.au </strong></p>.
```

I want to display a part of this string with `<h:outputText escape="false">` (just content, no HTML tag). I tried `substring()`, but I don't know where html tag finish, so my form is broken. I want to get about 100 character only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question 100% correctly but if all the strings you are to display are roughtly in the format from your example then you may display them without html and shortened to 100 characters this way:

```
<h:outputText value="#{textExtractorBean.extractedText}"/>
```

And this is the bean:

```
class TextExtractorBean{
...
  getExtractedText(){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([a-z])+>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int firstIdxAfterOpeningTags = 0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        firstIdxAfterOpeningTags = matcher.end();
    }

    pattern = Pattern.compile("</([a-z])+>");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int firstIdxBeforeClosingTags = text.length();
    if(matcher.find()){
        firstIdxBeforeClosingTags = matcher.start();
    }

    String extractedText = text.substring(firstIdxAfterOpeningTags,
            firstIdxBeforeClosingTags);
    String shortenedText = extractedText.length() > 0 ? extractedText
            .substring(0,100) : extractedText;
    return shortenedText;
  }
...
}
```

Where *text* variable contains string like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can output text with the following JSF HTML Tag:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Your content here"  />
```